# multi-nested for loop C++ not finishing

Tags: c++, for-loop

I currently have a small assignment for my c++ college course. I'm currently running into an error where it runs the first two loops but then freezes and does not finishes the rest of the loops. the whole point is to printout a * diamond

an example would look like this if you entered the number 7:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```

this is what the code looks like currently:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(){
cout<<"How many lines do you want?";
int num_rows;
cin>>num_rows;
int row_average = (num_rows/2)+1;
for(int count=0; count<num_rows; ++count){
    int midpoint = row_average - count;
    int absolute = abs(midpoint);
    int spaces = absolute;


    for (int count_a = 0; count_a<spaces; ++count_a){
        cout<<" ";
    }
    for (int count_b = row_average; count_b<num_rows; ++count){
        int stars = count_b - spaces;
        for(int count_c = 0; count_c = stars; ++count_c){
            cout<<"*";
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Any answers or help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `count_b<num_rows` is one condition. How is it changed in the loop?

Comment: `for (int count_b = row_average; count_b<num_rows; ++count)` wrong var incremented.

Comment: @MikelF Ah, ok. I see now where you intended the replacement. Your first comment wasn't clear. Deleting my other comments. However, `count_c < stars` might be the actual intent.

Answer (score 2):

Is this below a typo?

```
for (int count_b = row_average; count_b<num_rows; ++count){
       ---------------------------------------------^^^^^
```

Shouldn't it be `++count_b`?
Also you're not outputting any newline character?

Comment: That fixes one of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1) In the second nested for loop you should increment count_b. So

```
for(int count_b = row_average; count_b < num_rows; ++count_b) {
```

2) In the last nested for loop you need to make the condition count_c less than stars, not equal to it. So

```
for(int count_c = 0; count_c < stars; ++count_c) {
```

3) Finally, you need a newline character or else all these stars will print on the same line

Comment: In 2) The OP code isn't checking for equality `==`, it's actually _assigning_ `count_c = stars`.

Comment: Thank you all this is very helpful!! probably a couple mistakes I missed thanks again